# paragraph styles don't work for addTextBreak()

Tags: php, phpword

```
<?php
include('PHPWord.php');

header('Content-Type: application/msword');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.docx\"");

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();
$section->addText('aaa', null, array('spaceAfter' => 0));
$section->addTextBreak(1, null, array('spaceAfter' => 0));
$section->addText('bbb', null, array('spaceAfter' => 0));

$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

The Word document that that creates can be found here:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/test.docx

In Microsoft Word if you click on the empty line and then open the paragraph dialog you'll see that the Spacing -> After value is 8pt (I'm wanting it to be 0pt) whereas for the aaa line and the bbb line it's 0pt (as expected).

I'm using Beta 0.6.3.

Any ideas?

Comment: check , https://github.com/tristanbes/PHPWord/blob/master/PHPWord/Style/Paragraph.php

Comment: @Chandu - what, exactly, are you proposing? That I do `$p = new PHPWord_Style_Paragraph(); $p->setSpaceAfter(1);`? If that's the case then how do I pass the `$p` variable to the PHPWord object? If you post some code that works I'll upvote it and will mark it as the answer. You'll get 25 points for the effort..

Comment: There is an old ticket about this issue for the old phpWord version (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/18). According to the ticket the issue is resolved in later PhpWord versions available at the GitHub project (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)